# Qual tamanho de uma query considerável grande?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Qual tamanho de um *query* considerável grande? Preciso fazer uma `function` para enviar *query* para o servidor mas não posso exceder o limite para não travar o servidor:

```
public function sqlExecute($sql_code) {
    if ($sql_code != "" && strlen($sql_code) < 1e6) { // O TAMANHO DA QUERY AQUI
        echo '1';
    }
    else {
        echo '2';
    }
}
```

Comment: SSH, não posso passa a memoria e nem o tempo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No MySQL você pode verificar isso com:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = "max_allowed_packet";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/ShowVariables.sql).

Esta mesma variável pode ser mudada no `my.ini` ou `my.cnf`. Ela pode ser até 1GB mas é provável que esteja configurada por *default* com 1MB.

Ou seja, não tem muito com o que se preocupar na maioria dos casos exceto mudar o valor desta variável, se necessário, o que raramente será. Se for necessário um tamanho muito grande deve-se pensar se aquela solução é ideal.

Pode estourar o tempo de execução do PHP se a *query* for grande demais.

Comment: Muito obrigado! E para estabelecer um tempo para tempo de execução? Por exemplo: se a query demorar 1 minuto para ser executada , parar .

Comment: Isto é outra pergunta, mas me geral há há tempo limite do ponto de vista do MySQL. Você pode ter outro limites, isto normalmente ocorre no PHP e se está rodando como *script* para web este tempo costuma ser relativamente baixo. Mas geral suficiente para quase todos as *queries*. Se não for suficiente, estratégias precisam ser adotadas para lidar com isto, mas como eu disse, isto é outro assunto.

Comment: Para aumentar o limite do time da request no php pode usar a função [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) passe zero como argumento dessa forma não será imposto limite de tempo. @misakie

Comment: @rray vale a pena ver isso aqui também http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time.